# import parameters for r.watershed - (watershed basin analysis program) tool from grass using Qgis 2.2

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, hydrology, watershed

I want to run this tool from Qgis 2.2 but i don't know how to use the PARAMETERS to run this tool.

[image]

The red frame are the PARAMETERS I don't know.

Can someone to tell me what those PARAMETERS are and what they mean?

Comment: Why don't you just google??? http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.watershed.html

Comment: hello what is **locations of real depressions** ? what is **amount of overland flow per cell** ?  what is **amount of overland flow per cell** ? what is **terrain blocking overland surface flow, for USLE** ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, not all of those parameters are required. To obtain the watersheds, you simply need to specify the input elevation model, a name for the output basins map and a threshold (cell units) to tell the software at which level to aggregate subwatersheds. In the worst case check the [r.watershed manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.watershed.html) which is also in the "help" tab of your screenshot ;-)

Comment: I particularly interested for USLE output parametres

Comment: if i use your details and run this tools (LS) factor for USLE and (S) factor for USLE outputs is empty raster

Comment: See http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region --> FAQs -> Q: I don't see anything! -> Answer... (on that page)